# for every <li> present .append() a <fieldset> with the .text() of the <li> in the <legend>

Tags: jquery

Man, I've been crashing my firefox with this issue lol.

```
$("#add-contact-to-prospect-file").live("click", function(e) {
    var $npac = $("#new-prospect-add-contacts"),
        addVal = parseInt($("#new-prospect-additional-contact").val(), 10) + $npac.find('li').length;

    while ($npac.find('li').length < addVal) {
        var nLi = $('<li><span>Contact ' + parseInt($npac.find('li').length + 1, 10) + '</span></li>').css('display', 'none');
        $npac.append(nLi);
    }

    $npac.find('li:hidden').each(function(i, obj) {
        $(obj).delay((i + 1) * 150).fadeIn(600);
    });
$npac.find('li').each(function(j, obj) {
            var fieldsetCount = $('#steps').children().length;
            while(fieldsetCount < $npac.find('li').length){
                $('#new-prospect-form').append('<fieldset>').addClass('step');
                fieldsetCount + 1;
                console.log(fieldsetCount);
            }
            console.log(j);
        });

    slideForm();

    return false;
});
```

The first half works like a charm, but then when I get to the logic to append a fieldset to my form it loops like crazy crashing the page.

Essentially, the user adds X amount of contacts and it gets appended to a list via `<li>` so it looks like this

```
<li>Contact 1</li>
<li>Contact 2</>
..etc..
```

then I want a fieldset to get addedd to my form with class of "step" for each of the `<li>'s` present passing the value of the `<li>` to the `<legend>`

what am I doing wrong? ;-(

my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s2xi/q4nRP/

Comment: Is there a live example?

Comment: You want `fieldsetCount++;`. `fieldsetCount + 1` won't do anything because you're not assigning it back to `fieldsetCount` (ie. `fieldsetCount = fieldsetCount + 1;`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing a lot of appends and looping way too many times.

```
// Cache these selectors because they arn't going to change.
var $npac = $("#new-prospect-add-contacts"),
    $npf = $('#new-prospect-form');
    $npac_input = $("#new-prospect-additional-contact");
$("#add-contact-to-prospect-file").live("click", function(e) {
    // Prevent default rather than return false
    // Lets the event bubble up the DOM
    e.preventDefault();
    var total = $npac.find('li').length,
        addVal = parseInt($npac_input.val(), 10),
        lis = [],
        fieldsets = [];
    // Push all the new elements in to the correct array
    for (var i = 1; i <= addVal; i++) {
        var text = 'Contact ' + (total + i);
        lis.push('<li style="display:none;"><span>' + text + '</span></li>');
        fieldsets.push('<fieldset class="step"><legend>' + text + '</legend></fieldset>');
    }
    // Then only append once.
    $(lis.join('')).appendTo($npac)
    // Then loop over all the new hiddden elements
    .each(function(i, obj) {
        $(obj).delay((i + 1) * 150).fadeIn(600);
    });
    // add all the fieldsets 
    $(fieldsets.join('')).appendTo($npf);

    //slideForm();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/petersendidit/q4nRP/2/

Comment: ooh, wow ya thats a different route i didn't think of. I see the logic flow there. One question, well two. 1. The code does work in the fiddle but won't work on the click event i my live site. 2. Any suggestion to how i would go about pre populating the fieldset with a pre defined form? I could do an ajax call per each loop cycle and append the results the fieldset being created. Is that advisable?

Comment: @s2xi can't tell you why it doesn't work on your live site, maybe create a jsfiddle with more code? If the form is the same each time then no only do the ajax call once and then add it to the fieldset in the for loop that pushes the strings in to the array.

Comment: The code works until it gets to the for loop, then it won't execute the looped items.

Comment: @s2xi thats the exactly same jsfiddle that you originally posted. Are you using my code in your site?

Comment: I was, I just forgot to re-save the fiddle. But I figured out that I had to move the variable declaration within the click event for them to catch.

Answer (score 2):

try this change:

```
$npac.find('li').each(function(j, obj) {
    var fieldsetCount = $('#steps').children().length;
    var licount = $npac.find('li').length;
    while(fieldsetCount < licount){
        $('#new-prospect-form').append('<fieldset>').addClass('step');
        console.log(fieldsetCount);
        licount--;
    }
    console.log(j);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `while` loop:

```
$npac.find('li').each(function(j, obj) {
    var fieldsetCount = $('#steps').children().length;
    while(fieldsetCount < $npac.find('li').length){
        $('#new-prospect-form').append('<fieldset>').addClass('step');
        console.log(fieldsetCount);
    }
    console.log(j);
});
```

I don't see any way for that loop to terminate. If it executes once, it's going to execute repeatedly, since `fieldsetCount` and `$npac.find('li').length` are not modified within the body of the loop.

Comment: the .find('li') should need to be modify since its pretty much a set static number. And yes your right, I should increment the count for fieldsetCount